# How can I save my YAML file to my cwd or to a relative path?

Tags: python, path, os.path

I have the following code that generates a `YAML` file, for those not familiar, let's just say this is a csv file:

```
with open(f'/tmp/{source}-fields.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    with open(f'/tmp/{source}.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
        yaml_file.write("namespace:\n")
        yaml_file.write(f"  {source}:\n")
        yaml_file.write(f"    description: {source_desc}\n")
        yaml_file.write(f"    fields:\n")        
        
        for row in reader:
            yaml_file.write("      {}:\n".format(row[0]))
            if "'" in row[1]:
                yaml_file.write('        description: "{}"\n'.format(row[1]))
            else:
                yaml_file.write("        description: '{}'\n".format(row[1]))
            yaml_file.write("        type: '{}'\n".format(row[2]))
            
        yaml_file.write("\nBook: {}\n")
        yaml_file.write("\nMarket: {}\n")
        yaml_file.write("\nDataset: {}\n")
```

What I want to do is to save the generated YAML file to the current directory or to a relative directory, for which I will provide a path. How can I do this?

My solution: In the second `with open()` statement, do I simply add `os.path.join()` at the end with my my file name, `yaml_file` as the first argument, and for the second argument, the relative path I want to save my YAML file into?

Comment: Why are you writing text instead of writing a dictionary and using `pyyaml` or `ruamel` to write your YAML?

Comment: I am new to writing to YAML files, thanks for the suggestion, I will look up `pyyaml` and `ruamel`. Guessing these are packages?

Comment: yes, as for your path question, just use a relative path as you would on the terminal, so something like `f"{source}.yaml"` or `f"somedir/{source}.yaml"`